# Regular Expression which allow hyphen in Domain name

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which accepts a hyphen in the email's ID in Domain name.
Currently I am using

`\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*`

e.g:

1. myname123@gmail-abc.com
2. myname@k-ko.com

Comment: please visit this link : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460404/regex-for-allowing-alphanumeric-at-the-starting-and-hyphen-thereafter"

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of DotNet's link

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`/^\w+@\w+(\-\w+).\w{3}$/`

Comment: Please have look at here http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt for valid TLDs and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses for email addresses

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(\w+[-.]?)*\w+$
```