# Strict matching with Regex

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex `(?=.*-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$` to match a text like this `stack-over-flow` but this also matches

```
-stack-over
stack-over-
----
stack--over--flow
```

How can I make this expression only match a text that looks like this:

```
stack-over-flow
abc123-def456-ghi789-so-on-and-so-forth-must-not-end-or-start-with-dash
```

Comment: @Wiktor Tried the answer on a multiline text, it matches the first line fine but next lines without dash/hyphen will also match:
stack-over-flow\n
stackoverflow\n
overflowedstack

Comment: You are not using the [suggested regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/460416/3832970) then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried the expression at regex101 and it matches multiple lines without dashes

Comment: If there must be a hyphen, replace last `*` with `+`, `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. I figured it out.